# HTTP could not register URL ... because TCP port ... is being used by another application

Tags: wcf, http, wcf-binding

First, I am not good in WCF.
I have a WCF service hosted in WindowsService.
Since sometime the service stoped to run because of the exception:

HTTP could not register URL http://+:8092/MyService/ because TCP port 8092 is being used by another application.

- Nothing uses this port, it says the same about any port I tried.
- SSL certificate is configured.

There are many machines that can start this service, but the most required (customer's) machine cannot.
I saw many posts in this site or anywhere else, but cannot find a solution.
I never see the post like "It helped me".
I am stuck several days already, help please.

Below the data from config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyCompany.MyApp.MyAppService" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataSupport">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8092/MyAppService" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8093/MyAppService" />
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="MyCompany.MyApp.IMyAppService" />
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="MyCompany.MyApp.IMyAppService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="tcpmex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataSupport">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpGetUrl="" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="True" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 7):

You are using WCF duplex communication with `wsDualHttpBinding`. In this case, WCF creates a HTTP socket on port 8092 to service client **callbacks**. Clearly the client was conflicting with IIS 5.X. (I guess you have XP and IIS 5.x)

To resolve this problem you have to provide a `clientBaseAddress` in the binding configuration on the client and specify a different port.

Sample client configuration:
[image: Client configuration snippet]

I hope that this is really the problem in your machine, please notify me about the results of this solution.

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the windows service as someone with admin privileges. Certain versions of Windows (2008/Vista and up) are picky about who can open ports. If that helps, then you certainly don't want to actually run the service as an admin, but it at least points you in the permissions direction.

Also, you mention an SSL cert, but it is an 'http' url, not 'https'. That seems unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do the following diagnostics steps:

Try hosting the WCF Service in a Self-Host manner (Console Application):

- use the class `HttpServiceHost`
- use this binding:  `var binding = new HttpBinding(HttpBindingSecurityMode.Transport);`
- `AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(YourServiceClass),binding,"https://url...");`

If it works for you it seems that you have problems in configuring the WCF service to work under Managed-Windows Service.

Lets me know your results :-)

Comment: Well the console code get the same exception:
<pre><code>
Type serviceType = typeof(MyService);
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
//var binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, "http://localhost:8092/MyService");
host.Open();

Comment: I did the sample app (console) according to your configuration and its worked for me. I need to know if you have an IIS installed in your machine.